# Flow sending 600 emails to single contact

Tags: visual-workflow, singleemailmessage

I have a flow that is being called via Apex. The flow is taking in a list of a custom object called "**Milestones**". The flow has a wait element that waits for **10 days** and then recalls another Apex InvocableMethod that uses the Milestone from the flow. From there the InvocableMethod sends an email to the Contact owner of the Milestone using the **SingleEmailMessage** messaging service. This should only be sending **one** email if the next Milestone has not been started on the Contact. Also if the email is sent the flow is restarted for the 10 day wait period with the same Milestone.

The main questions are:

1. Does starting a new instance of a flow **reset** the collection variables for a flow?
2. How would I go about preventing sending multiple emails in one instance of the flow?

Here is my code:

```
public class NudgeEmail {

    // Creates nudge emails for apropriate participants
    public static Boolean invokeFlow(List<Milestones__c> milestoneList) {
        Boolean flowInvoked = false;
        TriggerControlSetting__c trigControl = TriggerControlSetting__c.getValues('MilestoneTrigger');

        // Set parameters for flow
        Map<String, Object> params = new Map<String, Object>();
        params.put('Milestones', milestoneList);

        // Assign parameters to Flow, if nudge email is turned on start the flow
        Flow.Interview.NudgeEmailWait sendNudgeEmailFlow = new Flow.Interview.NudgeEmailWait(params);
        if (trigControl.IsNudgeEmail__c) {
            sendNudgeEmailFlow.start();
        }

        // Make boolean value for testing purposes.
        Milestones__c milestoneInFlow = (Milestones__c) sendNudgeEmailFlow.getVariableValue('Milestone');
        if (milestoneInFlow != null) {
            flowInvoked = true;
            return flowInvoked;
        } else {
            return flowInvoked;
        }
    }

    @InvocableMethod
    public static void sendEmail(List<Milestones__c> milestones) {
        Set<Id> oppIds = new Set<Id>();
        Map<Id, Milestones__c> milestonesToOppMap = new Map<Id, Milestones__c>();
        Map<Id, String> nudgeEmailWhiteListMap = new Map<Id, String>();

        List<Nudge_Email_White_List__c> nudgeEmailWhiteList = [
            SELECT
                Network_Partner__c,
                Email_Template_Id__c
            FROM Nudge_Email_White_List__c
        ];

        for (Nudge_Email_White_List__c newl : nudgeEmailWhiteList) {
            nudgeEmailWhiteListMap.put(newl.Network_Partner__c, newl.Email_Template_Id__c);
        }

        // Assign milestone opportunity Id's to a set and milestones to milestoneMap
        for (Milestones__c milestone : milestones) {
            oppIds.add(milestone.Opportunity__c);
            milestonesToOppMap.put(milestone.Opportunity__c, milestone);
        }

        // Query for all weight watcheer opportunities in oppIds
        // Also include network partners in nudge email white list map
        Map<Id, Opportunity> opportunityMap = new Map<Id, Opportunity>([
                SELECT
                    Id,
                    Name,
                    Last_Completed_Milestone__c,
                    Contact__c,
                    Network_Partner__c
                FROM Opportunity
                WHERE Id IN: oppIds
                AND Network_Partner__c =: nudgeEmailWhiteListMap.keySet()
        ]);

        List<Milestones__c> milestonesWithNextMilestoneNotAchieved = new List<Milestones__c>();
        List<Id> contactsToSendNudgeEmail = new List<Id>();

        // Find the appropriate Milestone for an opp, compare the opp last complete milestone to the applicableMilestone
        // name, if the the value is the same populate appropriate lists for sending nudge email and restarting flow
        for (Opportunity opp : opportunityMap.values()) {
            Milestones__c applicableMilestone = milestonesToOppMap.get(opp.Id);
            if (opp.Last_Completed_Milestone__c == applicableMilestone.Name &&
                (applicableMilestone.Date_Achieved__c > Date.Today().addDays(-21))) {
                milestonesWithNextMilestoneNotAchieved.add(applicableMilestone);
                contactsToSendNudgeEmail.add(opp.Contact__c);
            }
        }

        // Send nudge email and restart Send Email Flow with applicableMilestones
        if (!contactsToSendNudgeEmail.isEmpty()) {
            List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> nudgeEmailList = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
            Map<Id, EmailTemplate> emailTemplateMap = new Map<Id, EmailTemplate>([
                    SELECT
                        Id
                    FROM EmailTemplate
                    WHERE Id IN: nudgeEmailWhiteListMap.values()
            ]);

            for (Opportunity opp : opportunityMap.values()) {
                // get the value from map and also email template by converting id to string
                Id emailTemplateId = Id.valueOf(nudgeEmailWhiteListMap.get(opp.Network_Partner__c));
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage nudgeEmail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                nudgeEmail.setTemplateId(emailTemplateMap.get(emailTemplateId).Id);
                nudgeEmail.setTargetObjectId(opp.Contact__c);
                nudgeEmailList.add(nudgeEmail);

            }

            // Send nudge emails and restart NudgeEmailWait flow
            if (!nudgeEmailList.isEmpty() &&
                !milestonesWithNextMilestoneNotAchieved.isEmpty()) {
                // Send Emails
                Messaging.SendEmail(nudgeEmailList);

                // Set flow configurations
                Map<String, Object> params = new Map<String, Object>();
                params.put('Milestones', milestonesWithNextMilestoneNotAchieved);

                Flow.Interview.NudgeEmailWait returnValues = new Flow.Interview.NudgeEmailWait(params);
                returnValues.start();
            }

        }

    }
}
```